# How to get parent instance value in to child class in ruby?

Tags: ruby

I'm not able to get the instance values of parent class to the child class, My code is like this.

```
class TimeLine
    attr_accessor :tweets
    def initialize(tweets=[])
        @tweets = tweets
    end
    def print
        puts tweets.join("\n")
    end
end

class AuthenticateTimeLine < TimeLine
    def print
        authenticate!
        super
    end
    def authenticate!
        puts "authenticated!"
    end
end
TimeLine.new([1,2,3,4,5])
authenticate_timeline = AuthenticateTimeLine.new
authenticate_timeline.print
```

When I call super on the child class, I'm getting empty array.

Comment: `[1,2,3,4,5]` is the value of the instance variable `@tweets` for a particular instance of the class `TimeLine`. Instances of a child class of `TimeLine` cannot determine the instances, if any, of its parent, so there is no way to access that information from the child class (even if their were only a single instance of the parent class).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's because you initialize it with empty array, you don't pass any argument to `AuthenticateTimeLine.new`, so default `[]` is taken (compare your `TimeLine#initialize` method). If you passed your array as argument, it would work:

```
authenticate_timeline = AuthenticatateTimeLine.new([1,2,3,4,5])
authenticate_timeline.print
# 'Works' now!
```

Comment: Thanks. Well May I ask you one doubt, How to deligate task from one object to another?

Comment: You can use `Forwardable`, described here:
https://medium.com/whynotio/delegating-with-forwardable-in-ruby-82b2fe382d0e